# Angular Passing Resolved Objects To Ng-Model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I thought this should be something easy because I've done it before, but apparently the first time I got lucky, either that or Angular has some quirks I have not yet wrapped my head around.

What I'm trying to do is be able to edit a customer order. All customer orders are sent to the client from the database as JavaScript objects, using PHP.

That is fine, my problem is within Angular when I want to edit these orders, through a modal window (which has its own scope). Basically a form pops up in the modal that asks the user to edit the Javascript object, of course however no user wants to edit a raw object so it's a form with ng-models tied to that object. My problem is the ng-model doesn't seem to pick up my object reference.

So here we go (I have a plunker below):

This is the controller that fetches the customer order on the page the first time (before the user initiates the modal to edit the order):

```
controller: function($scope,$http,$stateParams,$uibModal) {
         $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://example.com/orderDATA',
        params: {id: $stateParams.id}
      }).then(function successCallback(html) {
        html.data[0].orderProperties =    JSON.parse(html.data[0].orderProperties); //format data from server so that JavaScript can play with it
        $scope.order =  html.data[0];
        $scope.edit = function (order) //function that launches modal window
        {
            var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
                templateUrl: 'EditOrderInstance.html',
                controller: 'EditOrderCtrl',
                scope: $scope,
                size: "lg",
                resolve: {
                    order: function() {
                        return order;
                    }}
            });

        }
      }); 
    }
```

The `edit()` function is called like so from the following template:

```
<div class="container" style="margin-top:2%;">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12" style="text-align:center;">
<p class="whiteNoPointy">Customer Name : @{{order.orderProperties.firstName + " " + order.orderProperties.lastName}}</p>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12" style="text-align:center;">
<p class="whiteNoPointy">Pickup : @{{order.orderProperties.pickupDate + " in " + order.orderProperties.location}}</p>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12" style="text-align:center;">
<p class="whiteNoPointy"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i> : @{{order.orderProperties.email}}</p>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12" style="text-align:center;">
<p class="whiteNoPointy"><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i> : @{{order.orderProperties.phone}}</p>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12" style="text-align:center;">
<button type="button" style="border-radius:0;" class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="edit(order)">Edit This Order</button> <button type="button" style="border-radius:0;" class="btn btn-danger">Delete or Refund This Order</button> <button type="button" style="border-radius:0;" class="btn btn-primary">Complete This Order</button> 
</div>
</div>
</br></br>
<div class="shipping whiteNoPointy text-center" ng-repeat="specific in order.order">
<div class="col-xs-12" ng-if="specific.quantity.value>0"><p>@{{specific.quantity.value}} @{{specific.Name}}</p></div>
</div></div>
```

This part works fine. However, when I *do* hit the edit function, that takes us into a new scope and a new controller, specifically the one below:

```
 app.controller('EditOrderCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$uibModal','$uibModalInstance', 'order', function($scope, $http, $uibModal, $uibModalInstance, order) {
        $scope.order = order;
```

So as is hopefully clear, all I did was pass the order object to the modal.

Now to me, all I've done is pass the same order object around, and now to this new controller. But the problem is that when I investigate this latest order it has no `$$hashkey`. I say this because of the problem that follows, as I said I did this before except in that instance I passed the order object from inside an ng-repeat, and the last step worked. But here when I do it it doesn't work.

What I mean is, when I try to have the models in the modal template line up with the order object passed to the modal's controller, they don't. I just get blank inputs, which isn't good because to edit a customer order you need to now what the current order is, otherwise it's like you are starting over.

Here is the template with the `ng-model`.

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="EditOrderInstance.html">
       <div class="modal-header" style="text-align:center;">
            <h3 class="modal-title">Edit Order</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" style="text-align:center;">
        <form name="order" novalidate>
    <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstName" class="form-control" ng-model="order.orderProperties.firstName"  ng-minlength="2" required>
    <p ng-show="orderorderProperties.firstName.$error.minlength" class="warning">Please put your full first name.</p>
  </div>
  <button ng-disabled="order.$invalid||totalPrice===0" ng-click="submitOrder()" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer" style="text-align:center;">
            <button class="btn toggledz" type="button" ng-click="save()">Submit</button>
            <button class="btn" type="button" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </script>
```

Notice the `order.orderProperties.firstName` ng-model. This is there, I console log it from the modal's controller and I can see it is set, but the model is blank. So why is this the case? Why did it work before when the console.log() showed the object was passed with a `$$hashkey`? I can't pass from an ng-repeat again because I only have one order, so there is nothing to iterate over in the first template.

Please assist. I need to be able to edit the order using ng-model, so that the admin can edit the order and send a new order object back to my server.

**Edit: Added a plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/x6FPiS6OtF2gdn4ZtFyJ?p=preview**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by changing the variable name, I guess for some reason it was looking to the old `$scope.order` instead of the one resolved to the modal?

Anyway, here is a working plunker...

**https://plnkr.co/edit/AZpeFGaBktFjSr2SL2Rv?p=preview**

Answer (score 0):

From the first look, the problem appears to be with your resolve function

```js
controller: function($scope,$http,$stateParams,$uibModal) {
         $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://example.com/orderDATA',
        params: {id: $stateParams.id}
      }).then(function successCallback(html) {
        html.data[0].orderProperties =    JSON.parse(html.data[0].orderProperties); //format data from server so that JavaScript can play with it
        $scope.order =  html.data[0];
        $scope.edit = function (order) //function that launches modal window
        {
            var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
                templateUrl: 'EditOrderInstance.html',
                controller: 'EditOrderCtrl',
                scope: $scope,
                size: "lg",
                resolve: {
                    order: function() {
                        return $scope.order;
                    }}
            });

        }
      }); 
    }
```

Your resolve function for order should return $scope.order
Try it and let me know if this works. I am just going with the instincts

Comment: I had that before, I changed it to `order` in the hopes that it would be a more direct object reference. Both `$scope.order` and `order` in this case refer to the same object, and both of these options don't yield the desired result.